# Systemd: Some lines were ellipsized

Tags: vpn, systemd

I would like to install vpnautoconnect on Kubuntu 15.04.
After compilation (no ppa available), the deamon can't start:

```
$ systemctl status vpnautoconnect.service
● lvpnc.service - LSB: Start the VPNautoconnect daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/lvpnc)
   Active: active (running) since lun. 2015-04-27 19:08:06 CEST; 3min 51s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1604 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/lvpnc start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/lvpnc.service
           └─1668 /usr/local/bin/lvpnc

avril 27 19:08:06 guillaume-m2n systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start the VPNautocon....
avril 27 19:08:06 guillaume-m2n lvpnc[1604]: * Starting VPNautoconnect Daemon
avril 27 19:08:06 guillaume-m2n lvpnc[1604]: ...done.
avril 27 19:08:06 guillaume-m2n systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start the VPNautoconn....
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

What means the last line ?
What is possible to try ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this command to get full lines:

```
systemctl -l status vpnautoconnect.service
```

Comment: Thanks, so the daemon works. But not the interface...